# Detecting changes to a model within the same component - Angular

Tags: angular, onchange

I know that we can use @Input with onChange hook to detect changes done in the parent component within the child component. 
But my use case is to detect changes done to the model within the same component. 
component.ts:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    private myExmapleModel: MyModel;

    ngOnInit: void {
           this.momyExmapleModeldel = new MyModel('', '', '');
    }

}
```

I two-way bind this myExampleModel to the template html and want trigger a function when a value in MyModel instance changes, within the same MyComponent. How can I do that?

Comment: do you use `([ngModel])="myExmapleModel"` in html?

Comment: yeah. But I want to trigger a custom function on a value change.

Comment: use `ngModelChange`, see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using your `myExmapleModel` in html like this:

```
<input ([ngModel])="myExmapleModel">
```

You can use `ngModelChange` callback like this:

```
<input [ngModel]="myExmapleModel" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to detect change on input, use input-event or want to detect change on focus-away i.e. cursor not in input box, use change-event

```
<input [(ngModel)]="name" (input)="changed()" />

<input [(ngModel)]="name" (change)="changed()" />

changed() {
  console.log('name changed')
}
```